# Disabling XML schema when using GML3 decodeFeatureCollection in GeoTools

Tags: geotools, xml, gml

I wrote some code based on http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/xml/geometry.html#id6

```
GML gml = new GML(Version.GML3);

try {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.gml");   

    SimpleFeatureIterator iter = gml.decodeFeatureIterator(in);

    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        SimpleFeature feature = iter.next();
        System.out.println("Properties: "+feature.getProperties());
    }
}
```

This works well for most of my files but some other dataset comes with a XML schema that points to an offline host and a non-existent .xsd file. I trust the files so I would just like to ignore the schema.

How can I make GeoTools ignore the XML schema?

Searching online I found suggestions to do eg parser.setStrict(false), for example in https://github.com/boundlessgeo/geotools-2.7.x/raw/master/demo/gmlparsing/src/main/java/org/geotools/demo/gmlparsing/GMLParsing.java ,  but that uses a different approach in reading the file. If I created a Parser object, how do I tell gml.decodeFeatureIterator() do abide it?

I am very new to GeoTools so this question might be very confused.